# How do I remove a choice conflict in JavaCC?

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, javacc

My production rules are as follows:

```
OtherNonTerminal := NonTerminal | {}
NonTerminal := <TOKEN>:A() | <TOKEN>:A(), Nonterminal()
```

In JavaCC, NonTerminal has a choice conflict:

```
void OtherNonTerminal() : {}
{
    Nonterminal() | {}
}

void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
|
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA> Nonterminal()
}
```

Would this be one way to get rid of the choice conflict and will the program worked as specified like my NonTerminal production rule?

```
void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A() (<COMMA> NonTerminal())? 
}
```

Comment: I took out the `LOOKAHEAD(3)` that was at the start of the first alternative in the first implementation of `Nonterminal`. I did so because I think it wasn't relevant to the central question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why is there a problem

In JavaCC, the default method of deciding which branch to take is by looking at the next token.  It that token is compatible with the first choice, the first choice is taken and that decision is not reversible.  There is no backtracking.

So look at the choice

```
void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
|
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA> Nonterminal()
}
```

and suppose the next token in the input is `<TOKEN>`. The first choice will be taken regardless of whether there is a `<COMMA>` later on. In other words

```
  <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
| <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA> Nonterminal()
```

is equivalent to

```
  <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
```

Except the first will produce a warning message since JavaCC sees that what you have written doesn't make sense.

---

## A good solution

The answer to your question is "yes".  One solution is to do what you did and factor out the common prefix

```
void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A() (<COMMA> NonTerminal())? 
}
```

---

## A solution that might be better, depending

If, for some reason, you really don't what to factor, you can also do the following

```
void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    LOOKAHEAD( <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA>)
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA> Nonterminal()
|
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
}
```

Here, the parser will look ahead in input stream.  If it sees the comma, the first choice is taken.  Otherwise, the second.

This might be useful if the semantic actions are different in the two cases.  E.g.

```
  LOOKAHEAD( <TOKEN> <COLON> A() <COMMA>)
  <TOKEN> {doSomething();} <COLON> A() <COMMA> Nonterminal()
|
  <TOKEN> {doSomethingDifferent();} <COLON> A()
```

---

## A nonrecursive solution.

A third alternative is

```
void Nonterminal() : {}
{
    Foo() (<COMMA>  Foo() )*
}

void Foo() : {}
{
    <TOKEN> <COLON> A()
}
```

Comment: Hello, could another alternative be, `<TOKEN> <COLON> A()[<COMMA> NonTerminal()]` ? @TheodoreNorvell

Comment: I have updated my question because NonTerminal is used by another none terminal. @ TheodoreNorvell

Comment: I updated the question to what I should have really asked. Which was would `<TOKEN> <COLON> A() (<COMMA> NonTerminal())?` be the right fix for the problem.

Comment: In a BNF production `[ ... ]` is the same as `( .. )?`.  So the answer the question in the first comment is "yes".

Comment: With respect to your second comment, it make no difference how or whether the nonterminal `NonTerminal` is used.  The same three ways of implementing `NonTerminal` that are in my answer will all work.

Comment: Oh, I can see that now, your explanation was very good, thanks! @TheodoreNorvell

Comment: With respect to the third comment, I have rewritten the answer.